# How to loop through each textbox and set the textbox value to disabled in all other textboxes if one is entered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one table.Inside table i have some textboxes.I want to disable all textboxes with
   with same name after one is entered.
   How to do it with jquery?
  I have used the same thing for select box like below.

```
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
       $('select[name*="course"]').live('change', function() {
    $('select[name*="course"] option').attr('disabled',false);

    // loop each select and set the selected value to disabled in all other selects
    $('select[name*="course"]').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $('select[name*="course"]').not($this).find('option').each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('value') == $this.val())
                $(this).attr('disabled',true);
        });
    });

});
});
</script>

But i want to do it for textboxes.How to do?
```

Comment: Your code so far? HTML? JS?

Answer (score 3):

Set a `change` event, check the length. If there's a length, disable all others with the same name:

```
$("table input:text").change(function() {
    if (this.value.length > 5) {
        $("table").find("input:text[name=" + this.name + "]").not(this).prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Edit: Taking @adeneo's advice!

Comment: You probably meant `find()`, not `filter()`, and maybe add a `not(this)`

Comment: @adeneo -- Ahh yes - aand yes. Edited!

Answer (score 1):

## Idea:

On a textfield change:

1. check if there has been a value entered, that triggers the disable
2. get the name of the change text field
3. search for all other text fields and set them to disabled (or enabled as detected in 1st step)

## Code:

```
$('input[type=text]').on('change', function () {
    var disable = $(this).val().trim().length > 0; // only disable if something has been entered
    var textBoxName = this.name;              // get the name of the current textbox
    $('input[name='+textBoxName+']')          // select all textboxes /w same name
        .not(this)                            // except for the current ont
        .prop('disabled', disable);           // and set them disabled
});
```